# why we must declare activities and service in android manifest file?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

if I have a `Service` or an `Activity` that I want to be started only by another `Activity` in my app, do I need to declare it in the manifest? I.e., I always launch a secondary activity from the primary activity of my app that directly points the secondary activity's class (no intent filter resolution), is still necessary to declare the secondary activity in the manifest?

And what if I don't want anyone outside my app to be able to launch my secondary activity?

Answer (score 1):

1.YES
2.YES
3.set exported false in the manifest.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
What is Manifest?
```

Manifest file for an android application is a resource file which contains all the details needed by the android system about the application. It is a key file that works as a bridge between the android developer and the android platform. It helps the developer to pass on functionality and requirements of our application to Android. This is an xml file which must be named as AndroidManifest.xml and placed at application root. Every Android app must have AndroidManifest.xml file. AndroidManifest.xml allows us to define,

The packages, API, libraries needed for the application.

Basic building blocks of application like activities, services and etc.

Details about permissions.

Set of classes needed before launch.

```
Do I need to declare it in the manifest?
```

Yes

```
 Is still necessary to declare the secondary activity in the manifest?
```

Yes

```
What if I don't want anyone outside my app to be able to launch my secondary activity?
```

android:exported="false"

Answer (score 0):

We must declare  in AndroidManifresh according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

> Declares an activity (an Activity subclass) that implements part of
>   the application's visual user interface. All activities must be
>   represented by  elements in the manifest file. Any that are
>   not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be
>   run.